# Laravel - Pass multiple values to Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

part of my .vue:

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['photog-Id', 'gal-Id', 'photo-Id'],
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    },

    methods: {
        setfavorite(){
            axios.get('/' + this.photog-Id + '/' + this.gal-Id + '/' + this.photo-Id + '/like')
                .then(response => {
                    alert(response.data);
                });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

my .blade:

```
<div>
   <set-fav photog-Id="{{$gallery->user->phcode}}" gal-Id="{{$gallery->galcode}}" photo-Id="{{$photo->filename}}" ></set-fav>
</div>
```

for some reason only photog-Id value gets passed, while the other two are not being passed.. why?

also, when i compile css and js, do i have to upload only the compiled ones or also the uncompiled ones to my server?

Comment: Try this 
<div>
  <set-fav 
    :photog-Id="{{$gallery->user->phcode}}" 
    :gal-Id="{{$gallery->galcode}}" 
    :photo-Id="{{$photo->filename}}">
  </set-fav>
 </div>

Comment: @adrshk thanks.. unofrtunately no luck.. i get this error in console: `Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Invalid or unexpected token in

    2AMJJK1

  Raw expression: :photog-id="2AMJJK1"
`

Comment: @adrshk, these props are not reactive so he doesn't have to bind them i.e. use `:` or `v-bind:`

Comment: @kidA ohkay, thank you : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using kebab-case for your props in your blade file you need to use camelCase in your vue file. More specifically:

```
props: ['photogId', 'galId', 'photoId']
```

and your async call becomes

```
axios.get('/' + this.photogId + '/' + this.galId + '/' + this.photoId + '/like')
```

Also, the compiled files should be git-ignored. When you deploy a new version of your js/css files your deployment tool should take care of compiling them and adding them to the `public` folder of your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! unfortunately it does not work.. i see this in console: `GET www.mysite.com/2AMJJK1/undefined/undefined/like 500`

Comment: That's better to what you were having before since now it compiles the template successfully without any errors. Have you tested whether your `$gallery->galcode` and `$photo->filename` produce actual values? In kebab case, all letters are written in lower case and the words are separated by a hyphen or minus sign whereas in camelCase, each word within a compound word is capitalized except for the first word.

Comment: Thank you! yes they produce values.. this is from the source of the page in the browser: ` <set-fav photog-Id="2AMJJK1" gal-Id="D1C8652A" photo-Id="IMG_4432-Modifica.png" ></set-fav>`

Comment: It looks like the new app.js file is ignored.. i replaced the axios part with console.log and it still gives the same error as above.. is it somehow saved in cache?

Comment: refreshing with shift pressed did the trick! thank you its working now!

Comment: Great! Since it's a vue file you updated, you need to re-compile it in order to see the changes. Glad it worked!

Comment: I did recompile it.. but for some reason the browser kept using the old one..

Comment: I see, the reason is that browsers cache the assets so they don't have to re-download them every time you refresh the page. A way to overcome this, is to stick a random string at the end of your script tag i.e. `<script src='my_lib.js?v=109213></script>` that will be updated each time you have a new version. This way, the browser will know that it cannot use a cached version and it will fetch the newest one.